# Attempt to build Cassandra Lucene index failed, cannot checkout version 4.0.7

Tags: cassandra, git, lucene

Lucene Index is managed by Instaclustr (https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-lucene-index) in Cassandra 4.x instead of Stratio who supported till V3.x.
I have tried to test the Index creation but failed with below issues.
Anyone please help. I have raised this in git but somehow missed by team.
It would be of great help if anyone who successfully implemented this can share steps.

```
~/cassandra-lucene-index$ git checkout 4.0.7
error: pathspec '4.0.7' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

[image]

Subsequently below step failed also

mvn clean package

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the list of releases](https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-lucene-index/releases), there doesn't appear to be one for Cassandra 4.0.7, just for 4.0.4.

There is however [a branch for C* 4.0.7 named `cassandra-4.0.7`](https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-lucene-index/tree/cassandra-4.0.7) which you could try to build.

In the meantime, I'm going to reach out to friends at Instaclustr to get them to comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think Erick is right here.  Try checking out the `cassandra-4.0.7` branch, do a `git pull origin cassandra-4.0.7` and then a `mvn clean package`.

```
$ git checkout cassandra-4.0.7
$ git pull origin cassandra-4.0.7
$ mvn clean package
```

Comment: Still same error:                                                                                        
VirtualBox:~/cassandra-lucene-index$ git checkout cassandra-4.0.7
error: pathspec 'cassandra-4.0.7' did not match any file(s) known to git
VirtualBox:~/cassandra-lucene-index$ git pull origin cassandra-4.0.7
warning: redirecting to https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/
fatal: couldn't find remote ref cassandra-4.0.7

Comment: I directly downloaded jar file "cassandra-lucene-index-plugin-4.0.4-1.0.0.jar"
 from https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-lucene-index/releases and put it to $CASSANDRA_HOME/lib. Restarted cassandra and then able to create Index

Comment: but seems its not working as I am still getting prompt to use allow filtering

Comment: created Lucene Index country_index_organization on mymovie.organization but its still asking for ALLOW FILTERING
Dropped Lucene index and created secondary index. It worked

Comment: Hello all, I am able to implement lucene index successfully. Thanks all for your help